# Word that means "in good condition"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example sentence:

> People always fill their houses with stuff. Stuff not __ enough
>   to be useful or cheap enough to be thrown away.

Is there a word that means "in good condition"? Basically, a word that means "healthy" but applied to machines/devices/tools.

Comment: maybe you are looking for "fit"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[***good enough***](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/good%20enough) precisely describes *in good condition*

Stuff not ***good enough*** to be useful or cheap enough to be thrown away.